# n! combinations, how to find best one without killing computer?

Tags: algorithm, math

I'll get straight to it. I'm working on an web or phone app that is responsible for scheduling. I want students to input courses they took, and I give them possible combinations of courses they should take that fits their requirements.

However, let's say there's 150 courses that fits their requirements and they're looking for 3 courses. That would be 150C3 combinations, right?.

Would it be feasible to run something like this in browser or a mobile device?

Comment: maybe brute force isn't the answer

Comment: That's over 1/2 million combinations.  That's a bit much for client-side code:  You probably need a narrowing condition of some sort

Comment: what's the definition of `requirements`? If any 3 of the 150 courses are ok, then it seems no way out.

Comment: I'm confused...how is the student going to look through 1/2 a million suggestions?

Comment: The student doesn't really have to go through all 1/2, after they're calculated I plan to order them according to gap hours or difficulty or whatever they choose. That way they only probably need to see the first few.

Comment: If you can shift the processing to server-side, you can use branch-and-bound to build a search tree with a prune function.  Once the algorithm has finished, you can select the best n possibilities.  That would relieve the client of the majority of the computing requirements.

Comment: You probably much rather want to give a user 150 choices (of which to pick 3) rather than 1/2 a million. You can even allow the data to be filtered (by department?).

Comment: With any ordering, if any subject stands out slightly above the rest, you'll likely end up with something like this: `ABC, ABD, ABE, ABF, ..., ACD, ACE, ACF, ACG, ...` (worst case, I think as much as 149*148 = **22052 groups containing A in a row, all before anything else**), now if said user doesn't want to take said subject (`A`) that would be a rather significant problem.

Comment: With a half-million permutations, I should think you'd want to get the user's scheduling, difficulty, and other requirements *before* searching the tree. Make the user's choices do your pruning for you, until you have a manageable number of results (which you should be able to calculate beforehand), and provide a 'save' feature so the user can compare possible schedules and weigh her options.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need a smarter algorithm which can prune the search tree. Also, if you are doing this for the same set of courses over and over again, doing the computation on the server would be better, and perhaps precomputing a feasible data structure can reduce the execution time of the queries. For example, you can create a tree where each sub-tree under a node contains nodes that are 'compatible'.

Comment: That is what I'm trying to do, the 150 courses is after filtering out 800~

I guess I just need to keep filtering out even more.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like you're viewing this completely wrong.  At most institutions there are 1) curriculum requirements for graduation, and 2) prerequisites for many requirements and electives.  This isn't a pure combinatorial problem, it's a dependency tree.  For instance, if  Course 201, Course 301, and Course 401 are all required for the student's major, higher numbers have the lower numbered ones as prereqs, and the student is a Junior, you should be strongly recommending that Course 201 be taken ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

Yay, mathematics I think I can handle!

If there are 150 courses, and you have to choose 3, then the amount of possibilities are `(150*149*148)/(3*2)` (correction per jerry), which is certainly better than 150 factorial which is a whole lot more zeros ;)

Now, you really don't want to build an array that size, and you don't have to! All web languages have the idea of randomly choosing an element in an array, so you get an element in an array and request 3 random unique entries from it.

While the potential course combinations is very large, based on your post I see no reason to even attempt to calculate them. This task of random selection of k items from n-sized list is delightfully trivial even for old, slow devices!

Is there any particular reason you'd need to calculate all the potential course combinations, instead of just grab-bagging one random selection as a suggestion? If not, problem solved!

Comment: If the order of the classes don't matter, then it is in fact 150 choose 3. That is equal to `(150*149*148)/(3*2)`, however, not `150*149*148`. That leaves 551,300 possibilities.

Comment: @jerry Ah, thought I forgot something about that function. Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1 (Time\Space costly)**: let the user on mobile phone browse the list of (150*149*148) possible choices, page by page, the processing is done at the server-side.

**Option 2 (Simple)**: instead of the (150*149*148)-item decision tree, provide a 150-item bag, if he choose one item from the bag, remove it from the bag.

**Option 3 (Complex)**: expand your decision tree (possible choices) using a dependency tree (parent course requires child courses) and the list of course already taken by the student, and his track\level.

As far as I know, most educational systems use the third option, which requires having a profile for the student.